# How to use sub-protocols with generics and multiple-conformance to force a consistent API in a Swift framework?

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance, protocols, multiple-inheritance

I'm trying to use sub-protocols, multiple inheritance (multiple conformance?), and generics to help ensure a data-collection framework I'm working on maintains a consistent API once several other developers start contributing sometime in the future.

I have several types of data I'd like to record that all need timestamps, but I don't want a generic "DataSample" to ever get instantiated (hence the use of protocol instead of class/struct), since it doesn't ever make sense to have a DataSample that isn't from a specific data-source:

```
protocol DataSample {
    var timestamp: Double { get set }
}

struct VideoSample: DataSample {
    var timestamp: Double
    var width, height: Int
    var pixelData: Data
}

struct GyroSample: DataSample {
    var timestamp: Double
    var x, y, z: Float
}
```

I'm trying to use some protocols and sub-protocols to keep all appendSample(sample:) functions as similar as possible (this code section probably needs to change somehow):

```
protocol Recorder {
    // This protocol only exists in an attempt to
    // make all sub-protocols use a consistent API
    func appendSample<T: DataSample>(sample: T)
}

protocol VideoRecorder: Recorder {
    func appendSample<VideoSample>(sample: VideoSample)
}

protocol GyroRecorder: Recorder {
    func appendSample<GyroSample>(sample: GyroSample)
}
```

I'd like to allow for custom recorder implementations which can record from multiple data sources. For instance, maybe I want to write video data to a video track in an MOV and Gyroscope data to a metadata track in the same MOV:

```
class CustomRecorder: VideoRecorder, GyroRecorder {
    func appendSample<VideoSample>(sample: VideoSample) {
        // I want all recorder implementations which conform to
        // VideoRecorder to have some sort of function like this.
    }

    func appendSample<GyroSample>(sample: GyroSample) {
        // I want all recorder implementations which conform to
        // GyroRecorder to have some sort of function like this.
    }

    func appendSample<T>(sample: T) where T : DataSample {
        // I DON'T want this function to exist at all, but if I
        // don't have it here, I get a compile error saying:
        // "Type 'CombinedRecorder' does not conform to protocol 'Recorder'"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Protocol inheritance will not lead to what you are looking for, as this will not require the programmer to implement the same function declared in the inheriting protocol. There isn't a way of forcing a certain protocol to be implemented in a given way; protocols can only force concrete types to have some API, not other protocols. In essence, the `VideoRecorder` has the functionality of `Recorder` and can add whatever extra functionality it wants independent of what is in `Recorder`.

Be careful: the method blueprints in the protocols `VideoRecorder` and `GyroRecorder` define two functions with generic parameters with the same name as a type you have declared. Thus, the parameters of the functions **are not** the types you have declared as the generic parameter name takes precedence. There are some docs [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Generics.html) for more on generics.

It seems what you are trying to do can be satisfied with an associated type. For instance, you could define the following scheme (a bit involved):

```
// Samples
protocol DataSample {
    var timestamp: Double { get set }
}

struct VideoSample: DataSample {
    var timestamp: Double
    var width, height: Int
    var pixelData: Data
}

struct GyroSample: DataSample {
    var timestamp: Double
    var x, y, z: Float
}

// Recorder
protocol Recorder {
    associatedtype Sample: DataSample
    var samples: [Sample] { get set }
    mutating func appendSample(sample: Sample)
}

extension Recorder {
    mutating func appendSample(sample: Sample) { samples.append(sample) }
}

// Custom recorders
class VideoHandler: Recorder {
    typealias Sample = VideoSample
    var samples: [VideoSample] = []
    
    // Custom append
    func appendSample(sample: VideoSample) {
        
    }
}

class GyroHandler: Recorder {
    typealias Sample = GyroSample
    var samples: [GyroSample] = []
    
    // Default `append(sample:)` given in extension is used
}


// A specific type to handle film feeds
protocol FilmHandler {
    // Generic where clauses ensure that the sample types are correct for whatever types handle what is needed
    associatedtype VideoRecorder: Recorder where VideoRecorder.Sample == VideoSample
    associatedtype GryoRecorder: Recorder where GryoRecorder.Sample == GyroSample
    
    var videoProcessor: VideoRecorder { get }
    var gyroProcessor: GryoRecorder { get }
}

// Custom handler
struct VideoFeed {
    func videoSample() -> VideoSample! { nil }
}

class MyHandler: FilmHandler {
    typealias VideoRecorder = VideoHandler
    typealias GryoRecorder = GyroHandler
    
    var videoProcessor: VideoHandler { VideoHandler() }
    var gyroProcessor: GyroHandler { GyroHandler() }
    
    func handle(video: VideoFeed) {
        // Call a processor to do something
        videoProcessor.appendSample(sample: video.videoSample())
    }
}
```

The only difference here is that a single class needs to define other instances to handle different parts of the video; but this may lead to better-defined classes with more specific assignments.

Hopefully this helped.